# Do I need to provide references of past employments when I am already working at a employer for several years?

Tags: references

I have worked at my current place of employment for nearly six years now. My employer has only just decided to ask me for references. And I figured its a bit late for that but, I'm unsure if I have to supply them or not. I was told employers only had a limited time frame to ask for references. But I'm still unsure. If someone with knowledge of this could assist I would very much appreciate it. 
Thanks

Comment: This is insanity - you could have reasonably done three career moves in that time! What references does he want - previous employment or personal? Either way, I'd laugh in his face, personally. It's beyond ridiculous. You should have stated your locality, though.

Comment: I think this question needs some context. Has something dramatic happened that lead him to ask? What did he say he needs them for?

Comment: What is the problem with providing them with references?  Did you lie about them to get hired?  Also I assume this is US but can you confirm?

Comment: @Dan - And if after 6 years just short of being fully vested (its 7 years in many places) they decide that you are being deceptive and let you go?  If they provide a bad reference in the future?  It may be unreasonable but sometimes its just easier to comply with stupid requests than to fight them on principle.

Comment: Before laughing at anyone's face, I'd go through their workplace ethics/code of conduct policies to cross check if I have violated (unknowingly) any of it. If that comes as a positive, well then I have my answer. If not, keep looking for it, it wouldn't hurt for you to ask your Manager (politely) the reason of such a request, maybe he'll answer your question in a heartbeat saving you time going through all the if's and but's here.

Comment: It's England, and it's not for a promotion, although I have been offered supervisor role a few times. The company isn't that great, so I do not wish to move further up the ladder for them. I have not done anything wrong. She has asked everyone apparently but we have all worked there for several years. I just think it's ridiculous this late in my employment.

Comment: She also said it had to be written character references. I asked her why I can't give names and numbers for her to check and she just replied "it has to be a written reference" and that was that. Surely names and numbers are enough for an employer to check?!

Comment: @user14640 As you're in the UK, I'll be very surprised if there's *anything* they can do to make you provide these. I'd simply explain that you're unwilling to bother ex-colleagues and friends over a trivial box ticking exercise that serves no clear purpose. Then I'd laugh at them, again.

Comment: It's a bizarre situation. I would suggest asking them what the references are for? Are they for HR records? Are they to give to external customers? What information are they looking for? also ask them if you can use references from your current company - if you've worked there for six years they are going to be the most useful.

Comment: It is my current manager asking. She decided to jump on my back one day and I wouldn't take it. Next thing I know she is coming at me with this bull. She even typed up a sorry letter saying about needing references. She said its a legal requirement to my face but in the letter it didn't actually say that. It just said a requirement. I figured it was her way of showing who's boss. She is ok but doesn't like people challenging her opinions or thoughts. She's funny like that. She is only temporarily managing the store until our new manager starts.

Comment: It sounds like your employer has gone off the deep end. Just don't make eye contact with him while he's wearing his aluminum hat, and I think you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Since they are asking everyone, I would suspect they need the references for some contract they are trying to get. Just provide them.  You gain nothing by failing to provide them except negative attention from management which is generally somethingyou don't want.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more with this answer - rolling over to every whim of your employer is not the answer for workplace harmony. If this is the reason (Which is pure conjecture), the employer should be making this clear and asking nicely if references can be provided. That said, I've worked closely on big, multi million pound government contracts - I've had to provide my CV, proof of qualifications but NEVER a post-employment reference. It makes no sense, proves nothing and currently points to a hugely incompetent HR department.

Comment: It is stupid to make people mad for no gain. This is not rolling over to every whim, this is doing things that are in your own self-interest.

Comment: No, it's not - this is doing things because you don't want to "make a fuss", which is a terrible reason. Plus, you're ignoring the inconvenience for whoever has to provide the references.

Comment: Making a fuss is only something you do when it is important. How your managers perceive you is important and making a fuss over something this minor is just generally stupid.

Comment: It's not for any HR department as far as I'm aware. She likes to control things and when she can't it pisses er off.

Comment: Rule 1 is never piss off your boss without a really good reason.

Comment: @HLGEM I suppose this is where we differ - asking for references isn't minor 6 years into the job. It would be mostly unacceptable after 6 months, but 6 years is outrageous. Can you imagine contacting an employer from 6 YEARS ago - in fact, I don't even think I could, they've all moved on or retired.

Comment: @user14640 Your boss sounds like a horrible boss, and the long-run solution to problem is to get a new boss (find a new job).  To be completely honest, I'd tell the boss to shove the request up her ass, and restaff my position while she's at it.  The more prudent approach would probably be to make a complaint through your HR department and start sending out resumes.  Hopefully your HR department will reign her in and you won't actually have to find a new job, but you might get a better offer in the process.  Either way seems better than submitting to ridiculous, unreasonable requests.

Answer (score -2):

This is probably a good sign. If you've been around six years, they're probably thinking of offering a promotion, perhaps into management.  In such a situation you might be dealing with money, and the references will give them some idea of character, and presumably fiscal responsibility.

With that in mind, some of your references will be for people you worked for in the past and some will be current acquaintances. If you're not married but have a roommate, and the roommate isn't in some kind of trouble, this would be a good reference. If you went to Alaska with a friend for two weeks this is a good reference, presuming you still get along - one of the signs of true friendship is being able to tolerate each other while traveling.  Focus on people that would vouch for your character, presuming that you're the angel of empathy and enlightenment.

If being in management isn't exactly inspiring, you might say something like 'I'll have to dredge up the phone numbers and addresses, which may take a few days'.  In other words, go slow but don't go slow enough to raise doubts. Better to give them a couple of names and numbers off your cell phone contact list, with an indication you'll follow up with any more that they need in a day or so.

Comment: The people who downvoted this answer should explain what they dislike about it, because IMO it isn't obvious at all.

Comment: I agree, this is a somewhat dubious but still interesting viewpoint